# Using TableView first cell as header and issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I've used the first cell of tableview to be like header, for example in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
cell.label.text = "Header"

}else {

// fill up the data 
cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row]
}
```

And in `numberOfRowsInSection` I'm returning this :

```
return array.count
```

lets say I've 20 element in my array, and i reserved the first cell as header thus one of the elements will be eliminated. and if i increased the `array.count + 1` , and `array[indexPath.row + 1]` to solve the issue, so i get array out of bounds. i just want to use first cell as header and the rest of data in the next 20 cell. why couldn't that happen !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use `array[indexPath.row - 1]`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row > 0 {
        let entry = array[indexPath.row - 1]
    } else {
        //Configure the placeholder cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should put a placeholder in your array for the header, then the array.count will include the header, and the placeholder can be index properly with `indexPath.row` so you wont get an out of bounds error

otherwise if thats not an option you will have to make an exception when indexing your array, so like

```
//psuedo code
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
  return headerCell;
}
else {
  data = array[indexPath.row-1];

  return normalCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After get data, you should create an empty object for the header in your data.

[`array insertObject:@"header" atIndex:0];`

Answer (score 0):

Imho it would be easier to get the first element of your array, create your custom header view and remove it from your array so you will just have to handle normal 'uitableviewcells' with the stuff in the array and you don't need to use any conditions. There is a 'delegate' where you can setup the 'uitableviewheader' , thisshould also be the place where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two types

First is

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 )
{
   cell.textLabel.text = @"Header";
} 
else {
   cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row - 1];
   NSLog(@"The cell index is - %@",array[indexPath.row - 1]);
}
```

Second is

```
if (indexPath.row > 0 )
{
    cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row - 1];
    NSLog(@"The cell index is - %@",array[indexPath.row - 1]);
} 
else 
{
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Header";
}
```